# Which Demo code in Sphinx 4 is more appropriate for Real time Speech to Text Conversion?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sphinx4

I am working on the Java Sphinx4 API to recognize my speech in real time,I have gone through all the demo available with the source file,But I couldn't identify which demo to work on.

And How can I use transcribe demo to take input wav file real time and convert it into text.

I am working on a Speech Enabled Simulation Interface , Which requires pilot commands to get convert into text at Real time.

Any type of help is highly appreciate.

Comment: There should be a sample code in the name "TranscriberDemo.java" which uses a wav and converts it to text. Let me check how to give input realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) under Configuration section. You should be able to convert [TranscriberDemo.java](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java) to use the following.

LiveSpeechRecognizer uses microphone as the speech source.

```
LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
// Start recognition process pruning previously cached data.
recognizer.startRecognition(true);
SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
// Pause recognition process. It can be resumed then with startRecognition(false).
recognizer.stopRecognition();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me about changes that have I to make in the transcriberdemo.java file other than adding the above code. ?                      What will be the .wav file in the config.xml file ?